# Android Java Socket Cannot Read Data Sent From C# Server, However Data Being Sent To C# can

Tags: java, c#, android, network-programming

I have been able to establish a connection between a C# server and a Java Android Client, data can be sent to the C# server from an android client, however data being sent back to the Client is not received.

The code for the functions which send data on android:

```
public class ClientSendData implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            String MessageToSend = Operation + "|" + Data + "<EOF>";

            try {
                DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                dOut.writeUTF(MessageToSend);
                dOut.flush();

                DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                try {
                    msg = dataInputStream.readUTF();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Code Which Prepares The Socket:

```
 public class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

OnCreate And Events Which are called when button press happens, the Thread.Sleep on the main thread was added just as an additional debugging step and was just put in to see if the socket thread needed time to catch up, I know this is bad programming:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
    }

    public void SendMessageToServer(String operation, String data)
    {
        String MessageToSend = operation + "|" + data + "<EOF>";
        new Thread(new ClientSendData()).start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void ButtonClick(View view) {
        SendMessageToServer("1", "0000");
    }
```

the server code works when I use it with a C# client, the C# client is able to get the data back which is sent. this also works over LAN to, so I am confused as to why the android client is not working correctly, any help would be appreciated as I am new to Java and Android.

Comment: What OS you are running your C# server on might be important here. And wether it´s physical device or enumator that´s running android. I´ve had issues before receiving a binary data stream when I ran an android emulator under Windows. I did not control the backend. But those issues where completely non existent on a physical device or emulator on Linux or MacOS.

Comment: Your code is a mess. And in the wrong sequence to begin with. And you did not tell what the server sends to the client nor did you post code for it.

Comment: @max the client is run on a physical android device, the port is allowed through the firewall, I know that that is working cause I can get the clients message on the server, but when that is echoed back the phone can't receive it. The server has also been ran on Windows 10 and Windows server 2019

Comment: @blackapps I understand that the code is a mess, I am new to java and I have done alot of testing in that code so its quite messy. The server should just send back what was sent for now. But the use case for it is that the client can send a message like this 1|0000<EOF> this is what's being sent, the first number is the operation that the server would need to do middle is the data and <EOF> is to mark the end of transmission.

Comment: That does not bring us further. We still dont see server code. And for the client code: put all in one function. Connect, send data, read data and disconnect. Make it easy for us to follow you.